# Correct syntax for mutate_if

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I would like to replace `NA` values with zeros via `mutate_if` in `dplyr`. The syntax below:

```
set.seed(1)
mtcars[sample(1:dim(mtcars)[1], 5),
       sample(1:dim(mtcars)[2], 5)] <-  NA

require(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
    mutate_if(is.na,0)

mtcars %>% 
    mutate_if(is.na, funs(. = 0))
```

Returns error:

> Error in `vapply(tbl, p, logical(1), ...)` : values must be length 1,
> but `FUN(X[[1]])` result is length 32

What's the correct syntax for this operation?

Comment: for this particular task, you might also consider the simpler `tidyr::replace_na` rather than the more generic `mutate_if` approaches

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I learned this trick from the [purrr tutorial](https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2017/happy-r-users-purrr-tutorial-/), and it also works in dplyr.
There are two ways to solve this problem:
First, define custom functions outside the pipe, and use it in `mutate_if()`:

```
any_column_NA <- function(x){
    any(is.na(x))
}
replace_NA_0 <- function(x){
    if_else(is.na(x),0,x)
}
mtcars %>% mutate_if(any_column_NA,replace_NA_0)
```

Second, use the combination of `~`,`.` or `.x`.( `.x` can be replaced with `.`, but not any other character or symbol):

```
mtcars %>% mutate_if(~ any(is.na(.x)),~ if_else(is.na(.x),0,.x))
#This also works
mtcars %>% mutate_if(~ any(is.na(.)),~ if_else(is.na(.),0,.))
```

In your case, you can also use `mutate_all()`:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_all(~ if_else(is.na(.x),0,.x))
```

Using `~`, we can define an anonymous function, while `.x` or `.` stands for the variable. In `mutate_if()` case, `.` or `.x` is each column.

Comment: Purrr Tutorial has moved to https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2017/happy-r-users-purrr-tutorial-/

Answer (score 53):

The "if" in `mutate_if` refers to choosing *columns*, not rows. Eg `mutate_if(data, is.numeric, ...)` means to carry out a transformation on all numeric columns in your dataset.

If you want to replace all NAs with zeros in numeric columns:

```
data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))
```

Comment: working fine, one might use `if_else` instead to stay in the `tidyverse` and benefit for the additionnal check of the TRUE, FALSE type coherence

Comment: if you want to check if it's NA or equal to "NA" in the ifelse how you caan solve this (add another condition)

Answer (score 27):

```
mtcars %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0)
```

or more recent syntax

```
mtcars %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
                         replace_na, 0))
```

Comment: Simplicity is important. If a simple line of code can do the same thing as more complex, long code, I think it should be chosen instead.

Comment: This should be in the help page for `mutate_if`. Thanks for making my life easier.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `set` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mtcars)
for(j in seq_along(mtcars)){
  set(mtcars, i= which(is.na(mtcars[[j]])), j = j, value = 0)
 }
```

Comment: How might this be modified to only operate on numeric variables please?

Comment: @RickPack. You could change the `for(j in seq_along(mtcars))` to `nm1 <- names(mtcars)[mtcars[, unlist(lapply(.SD, is.numeric))]; for(j in nm1)`

Answer (score 3):

I always struggle with replace_na function of dplyr

```
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

this works for me for what you are trying to do.